# Colab Kernel Restarts Whenever Loading a Model From Tensorflow-hub

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I wanted to try out the embeddings provided in tensorflow-hub, the 'universal-sentence-encoder' to be specific. I tried the examples provided (https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder.ipynb)
and it worked fine. So I tried to do the same with 'multilingual' model but every time the multilingual model is loaded, the colab kernel fails and restarts. What is the problem and how can I get around this?

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import seaborn as sns
import tf_sentencepiece
import sentencepiece

# Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/1") // This is where the kernel dies.
print("imported model")
# Compute a representation for each message, showing various lengths supported.
word = "코끼리"
sentence = "나는 한국어로 쓰여진 문장이야."
paragraph = (
    "동해물과 백두산이 마르고 닳도록. "
    "하느님이 보우하사 우리나라 만세~")
messages = [word, sentence, paragraph]

# Reduce logging output.
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
  message_embeddings = session.run(embed(messages))

  for i, message_embedding in enumerate(np.array(message_embeddings).tolist()):
    print("Message: {}".format(messages[i]))
    print("Embedding size: {}".format(len(message_embedding)))
    message_embedding_snippet = ", ".join(
        (str(x) for x in message_embedding[:3]))
    print("Embedding: [{}, ...]\n".format(message_embedding_snippet))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues with the multilingual sentence encoder. I resolved it by specifying tensorflow version to 1.14.0 and tf-sentencepiece to 0.1.83, so before running your code in colab try:

```
!pip3 install tensorflow==1.14.0
!pip3 install tensorflow-hub
!pip3 install sentencepiece
!pip3 install tf-sentencepiece==0.1.83
```

I was able to replicate your problem in colab and this solution loaded the model correctly:

[image]

It seems to be a compatibility problem between sentencepiece and tensorflow, check for updates on this issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/345).
Let us know how it goes. Best of luck and I hope this helps.

EDIT: **If tensorflow version 1.14.0 does not work, change it to 1.13.1**. This problem should be resolved once compatibility between tensorflow and sentencepiece is figured it out.

Comment: Still having the issue... :(
The colab session keeps restarting with unknown reason when loading the model...

Comment: That is odd. Try: !pip3 install tensorflow==1.13.1 instead and don't forget to restart runtime first.

Comment: Glad it did :) Keep track of updates at the link I sent, will change answer accordingly so it works for everybody.